# docusign getDocument return blank pdf with issue in signature

Tags: docusignapi

iam using server side package of docusign to allow my customers to sign and download the signed file. After how customer complete sign i am trying to store the document but the pdf is blank. My accountId are in production. Any idea why?

```
  let dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();//simple init
    dsApiClient.setBasePath(args.basePath);
    dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + args.accessToken);
```

```
  let envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient),
      results = await envelopesApi.getDocument(args.accountId, args.envelopeId, args.documentId, null);
      fs.writeFile('test.pdf', data, 'utf8', (error_file) => {
        console.log(file_name)
      });//simple store binary to my hard drive
```

Answer (score 0):

was abled to store pdf with stream

```
const stream = fs.createWriteStream(tempFilePath, { flags: 'a' });
    stream.on('error', function(err: any) { 
      reject(tempFilePath);
    });
    stream.on('finish', function() {
      resolve(tempFilePath);
    });
    stream.end(data, 'binary');
```